Quickest way to find lowest value in dataframe from current row column value
For each row in the dataframe below, want to populate minlow and lowdate. minlow should find the lowest 'low' column in the future and then set minlow and lowdate. I have plenty of code examples using .loc/.iloc but these are slow as the dataframe is over 4Million records. Trying to find the most performant method.



Expected output




Index 0 would be nothing as no future records are lower


Index 1 would have minlow=277.97 and lowdate=2020-01-20 21:39:00


Index 2 would be nothing as it is already at the lowest


Index 3 would be nothing as no future records are lower


Index 4 would be nothing as it is the last record and no future records exist yet



                      date      low     minlow lowdate
0       2020-01-20 21:37:00    277.97    None    None
1       2020-01-20 21:38:00    277.98    None    None
2       2020-01-20 21:39:00    277.97    None    None
3       2020-01-20 21:40:00    277.98    None    None
4       2020-01-20 21:41:00    277.99    None    None

